# PiTFT: Cause terminal blanking to disable screen backlight, let touchscreen wake terminal

Tags: touchscreen, terminal, pitft

I have a raspberry pi model B rev 2, with the Adafruit PiTFT 2.8" w/ touchscreen. I'm running the standard raspbian install, after following the instructions [on this page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/easy-install).

What I want to do is set up the pi such that when the console blanks from inactivity (the blanking that's inactivity time is set with `setterm -blank VALUE`) it also disables the backlight of the PiTFT as described [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/extras), and when the console awakes due to kbd/mouse input the backlight is re-enabled.

I would also like a way to make a touchscreen press a method apart from kbd/mouse that will trigger the wake up, or if not that then a physical GPIO button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering from the code on [github](https://github.com/notro/fbtft-spindle/wiki/Appendix) you could edit the `drivers/tty/vt/vt.c` file. The function you are concerned with is the one that contains the boolean blank_timer_expired. 
[image]

To turn the backlight off through software you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/backlight-control) by adding `sudo sh -c "echo 'out' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio508/direction"`(see tutorial for full setup). This would be put in the if clause above right after `do_blank_screen(0)`. This would make the screen turn off at the same time that it blanks out. To turn it back on you would put the line `sudo sh -c "echo '1' > /sys/class/gpio/gpio508/value"` in the function above in the file right after `unblank_screen();`.

[image]

This would ensure that whatever triggers the screen to turn back on from blanking, will also turn the backlight on and whatever triggers the screen to blank will also trigger backlight to turn off. I believe this would include touching the screen.

Comment: As I understand, I need to recompile the kernel to implement this solution: where can I find the sources the patches for running the PiTFT itself? Or do I need to recompile and then apply patches afterwards. I've had a look in apt.adafruit.com, and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Yea...thats a problem, Im not sure but Ill look around and get back to you with my results.

Comment: On second thought, tell me if I am missing something - couldn't you just copy the "drivers/tty/vt/vt.c" file put it on another computer with a gcc compiler and edit it the file as shown above and recompile it. Then just put it back in your pi, delete the old file and reboot it. Obviously, you would not be able to have the touchscreen but would attach a monitor via HDMI or SSH into the pi.

Comment: @EinsteinJr.You should never ask a user to check mark an answer - it can seem like bullying. If the answer is a good one it will rise on its own.

Comment: Ok...understood.